# How to keep our changes on remotely provided souce

Tags: git

We are working on existing code and sometimes we get new version of it. We need to integrate our changes to new version and keep changing.
What is the easiest way to integrate new version to our code keeping our changes?

We are using git. When new version comes we copy and replace all files in our project. After that we go through every file and check if the changes were made by us or this is external change. If conflicts pop up we resolve it. After this big job we have new integrated commit. But we can miss something by doing it manually.

Is there a better way? How to make this process easier and more resistant to bug generation? What is the common solution for this situation?